# Is Windows 10 Anniversary Update required to work with Anniversary SDK?

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP Application and on August 2 Microsoft released new SDK along with Windows 10 OS Update. I have not received the official update yet but I have downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 which includes new Anniversary Update. My query is if I update Visual Studio will I able to work on my app even if new Windows 10 OS is not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), the Windows 10 SDK can be used with Windows 10 and Windows 8.1. You do not have to run the Windows 10 Anniversary Update to implement applications, that make use of those features. You cannot test those features exclusive to the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, unless you install the update.

Comment: Ok. My current app is targeting 10586 version. Can I use new API in that app?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: 10586 is the *"November Update"* (i.e. not the Anniversary Update). You cannot (directly) use features that were introduced in the Anniversary Update when targeting 10586.

Comment: Ok thanks. I more doubt I have, if I update Visual Studio and 10586 SDK is deprecated as new 14393 is installed then will my app at least work in emulator?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: Updating Visual Studio will not remove the older SDKs. They will still be there, and nothing gets deprecated. I haven't tried, whether you can use an emulator to run the Anniversary Update on a non-Anniversary Update machine, but I'd assume, that this is possible.

Comment: ok if I change target version to 14393 then it would be helpful to me when I update to Anniversary OS to check new features

Comment: If I change target version of my app to 14393, will it create any issues?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar: [Which version of the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) should I choose?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt590210.aspx)